# Swift: How to populate different array elements into groups?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to solve an array problem. 
I have an array of objects like below:

```
["Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

and trying to group them into a 2 dimentional array like below:

```
[["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"], 
["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"], 
["Banana", "Apple"]]
```

any idea how to do that using Swift?

Comment: What logic are you using for grouping the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any prior knowledge about the contents of the array, you could create arrays that contain unique elements this way:

```
let fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]

var output = [[String]]()

for fruit in fruits {
    if let arrayIndex = output.firstIndex(where: { !$0.contains(fruit) })  {
        output[arrayIndex].append(fruit)
    } else {
        output.append([fruit])
    }
}

print(output)
```

Which prints:

> ```
> [["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"], ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"], ["Banana", "Apple"]]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Will this work?

```
let array = ["Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
var groupArray:[[String]] = []

for x in array {
    var elementPushed = false
    for (index, y) in groupArray.enumerated() {
        if(!y.contains(x)) {
            groupArray[index].append(x)
            elementPushed = true
            break
        }
    }
    if !elementPushed {
        groupArray.append([x])
    }
}
```